# Can't get past the Ubuntu loading screen when installing

Tags: system-installation, 11.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 11.04 onto some custom made PC that my father in law tried building. It had Windows on it, but he wants Ubuntu so he asked me to do it. I've installed Ubuntu 11.04 on a few computers no issues, but on this computer I get to the all purple screen with the Ubuntu logo and the orange and white dots that light up. Like this:

[image: example]

The fan is also super, super loud and sounds like the whole thing is going to explode and has been running like this for 15 mins ish. Then, after about 15 mins the dots stop animating from orange to white and usually just stick at all orange.

Any ideas?

Comment: Install with the alternate CD. After the installation you should start Ubuntu with (nomodeset noplymouth).

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? What did you do?

Answer (score 3):

When you boot the disc you should see some other options for booting up, such as no acpi, no USB, no graphic installation, etc... I believe they are available by hitting the F1-F6 keys on Ubuntu boot discs.

Try different combinations of installation options, and see what happens. Also, if you manage to run an installation without the fancy loading image you will be able to see what's the actual error on the console.

Answer (score 2):

Try hitting the esc button during this process to find out what's really going on in the background. Also try another installation media.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too!
Its because your computer's hardware config. is low.
Press the down arrow button and you'll be able to see what's really going on. (:
If its something regarding your network config. just keep waiting (i had to wait for 30 mins coz my comp is very slow :P )!
After u login (for the first time) it might take sometime for the desktop to start.
But once its up it'll work just fine!
You can then configure your network manually.