# Why Fan running full speed with Ubuntu 14.04 on Asus R510VX?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, fan, asus

I have Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 10 on my new Asus R510VX laptop.  The fan is running full speed each time I boot on Ubuntu.
Here is the output of `sensors` command:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +31.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +32.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +29.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +30.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +27.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +28.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     25500 RPM
temp1:        +31.0°C  

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
```

I searched other threads of the issue but did not find a solution.

Hardware: Asus R510VX laptop
Ubuntu: 16.04
Dual-boot: Windows 10
Linux kernel: 4.4.0-34

Comment: When you type "uname -r" (to get kernel version) in the terminal what does it report? FTR my laptop is running at 59C - 72C and fan speed is 3963 RPM with youtube running. It was 80C with Ubuntu 16.04 install with Kernel 4.4 but then I upgraded to kernel in a few days 4.6.3 and then 4.71 and things are running much smoother now. Will try 4.7.2 soon because suspend/resume isn't perfect yet. Your temperature is extremely low and it appears your fan is working as an air conditioner IMO.

Comment: [This is a common problem with Asus laptops](https://www.google.ca/search?q=asus%20laptop%20fan%20always%20on%20askubuntu). Search around first and report back with your results.

Comment: my kernel version is 4.4.0-34. Do you think I should upgrade my Ubuntu version to version 16.04?

Comment: @O.Marlec Does the loud sound of the fan occur all the time when you run Ubuntu? Or does it run only when you boot? If it runs only when you boot, then it can be normal. I see nothing abnormal in your sensor data. - - Are you running Noveau drivers for your NVidia GPU?

Comment: Have you installed your graphics driver?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abnormally high temperature and fast fan speed at BIOS/Grub on Asus laptop after Ubuntu update](http://askubuntu.com/q/811518/255257), [Can't get past the Ubuntu loading screen when installing](http://askubuntu.com/q/62657/255257), [Laptop can't control fan speed after 16.04 upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/q/762057/255257) and [Fan noise in LG U460 in Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/799380/255257)